# How to include more than one class/sub-class in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, syntax, subclass

I have this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').toggleClass("visible");

    $('a.link').click(function(event) {
        // Over-rides the link
        event.preventDefault();
        // Sets the new destination to the href of the link
        newLocation = this.href;
        color = $(this).data("color");
        $('body').css('background-color', color );
        $('#holder').css('opacity','0' );
        // Delays action
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // Redirects to new destination
                window.location = newLocation;
        }, 250);
    });

    $('h1').click(function(event) {
        $('#holder').toggleClass("visible");
    });

});
```

I want to change the use of class `body` to something like `body.subsection.container`. How do I do this ?

Also I want to include more than one class so something like `body.subsection.container1`, `body.subsection.container2`.

Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Greg.

Comment: `$('body .subsection .container')` ?

Comment: ok great and as for including more than one class do i just put a comma to seperate ?

Comment: `body` is not a class but the tag name; `.body` would be a class reference.   Otherwise , you've answered zourself: Multiple classes on 1 element can be selected by concatenating the class specifiers without whitespace: `body.subsection.container`. Multiple selectors are concatenated by commas: `body.subsection.container1, body.subsection.container2`. Note that @adeneo's selector describes a `container` element being a descendant of a `subsection` element being a descendant of the `body` element.

Comment: me answering my own question , that is a first !

Comment: thanks for the support , my JS is weeeeaaakkk !!!

Comment: duplicate question !! if you have any question just do a search with proper keyword. If do not find exact match only then post your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean finding an element with class container1 or container2 somewhere in an element with class subsection somewhere in the body element, you would do:

```
$('body .subsection .container1,body .subsection .container2')
```

`body.subsection.container` would find a body tag that *itself* had class subsection and class container.

Comment: ok fair enough but you have used spaces between them in your example and then not in your conclusion, which one should i use as i can't get it to work

Comment: @user3504751 unless you have `<body class="subsection container">` you use the spaces.  that's what my final sentence means.